# Log4j2.xml configuration file not found after configuration change

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm having a problem with the log4j2.xml configuration file not being found after a change to the configuration file was made. Before the change the file was found and the simple logging was working. I haven't used log4j in a few years and have been making use of the java.util logging for application logging on the weblogic server so I decided to put log4j to use again.

I first create a simple configuration file, tested it out and everything was working just fine.

The original test configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Configuration>
     <Properties>
       <Property name="filename">/opt/www/log</Property>
     </Properties>
     <Appenders>
       <RollingFile name="StipLog" fileName="${filename}/stip-log.log" filePattern="${filename}/stip-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
           <PatternLayout>
               <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
            </pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
          <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
           </Policies>
       </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
      <Logger name="stip-debug" level="debug" additivity="true">
          <appender-ref ref="StipLog" level="debug"/>
      </Logger>
      <Root level="debug">
          <AppenderRef ref="StipLog"/>
      </Root>
    </Loggers>
  <Configuraiton>
```

Runing this code snippet in a backing bean for a page worked just fine with the original configuration file.

```
    LOGGER.info("APP Home Page: User: ".concat(userInfoBean.getUserName()));
    LOGGER.debug("DEBUG message!");
    LOGGER.error("ERROR Message", new NullPointerException("I AM NULL"));
```

That all went well so I decided to try and configure different appenders for each log level I wanted to use. I changed the original configuration to the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration>
    <Properties>
      <!-- For local logging change this porperty to a local directory. ex: C:\\Public\\log -->
      <Property name="LOGGING_ROOT">C:/Public/log</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <!-- file appenders -->
      <RollingFile name="debugLog" fileName="${LOGGING_ROOT}/app-debug.log" filePattern="${LOGGING_ROOT}/app-debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="DEBUG" maxLevel="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
      </RollingFile>
      <RollingFile name="infoLog" fileName="${LOGGING_ROOT}/app-info.log" filePattern="${LOGGING_ROOT}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
          <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="INFO" maxLevel="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
           <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
              </pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
          <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
          </Policies>
          <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
       </RollingFile>
      <RollingFile name="errorLog" fileName="${LOGGING_ROOT}/app-error.log" filePattern="${LOGGING_ROOT}/app-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
          <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="ERROR" maxLevel="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
          <PatternLayout>
             <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
            </pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
          <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
          </Policies>
          <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
      </RollingFile>
      <!-- console appender -->
      <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
      <Logger name="debug-logger" level="debug" additivity="true">
          <appender-ref ref="debugLog"/>
      </Logger>
      <Logger name="info-logger" level="info" additivity="true">
          <appender-ref ref="infoLog"/>
      </Logger>
      <Logger name="error-logger" level="error" additivity="true">
          <appender-ref ref="errorLog"/>
      </Logger>
      <Root level="all">
          <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
          <AppenderRef ref="debugLog"/>
          <AppenderRef ref="infoLog"/>
          <AppenderRef ref="errorLog"/>
      </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

After changing the configuration file I am now getting the following error message when the application is deploying.

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

The configuration file is in the same location as it was when the loggin was working, it's in the source default package. I moved it WEB-INF to see if that would make a difference but the same problem remains. I even changed it back to the original configuration and still have the same problem.

Comment: Did you change the status logger level as the error message recommends? If so what was the output from the status logger?

Comment: @D.B. I tried that but honestly I'm not sure where I need to add the command to do so. I tried setting it in the VM options hoping it would work when the app was deployingto my local weblogic server but it didn't. Strange thing is when I deploy the app to the stand alone development server the log files are created but are only written to intermittently.

Comment: Take a look at the [log4j2 FAQ page regarding debugging configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#troubleshooting)

Comment: I've already been there and tried it but I'll go through and do it again in case I did something wrong.